# Web scraping with R?

Tags: web-scraping

I have a dataframe which indicates, in column, an url.

```
test = data.frame (id = 1, url = "https://www.georisques.gouv.fr/risques/installations/donnees/details/0030.12015")
```

Using this, I would like to retrieve an element in the web page. Specifically, I would like to retrieve the value of the activity state.
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/51/t1fx.png

Thanks to my research, I was able to find a code which allows to select the element thanks to its "XPath".

```
library (rvest)

page = read_html ("https://www.georisques.gouv.fr/risques/installations/donnees/details/0030.12015")
page%>% html_nodes (xpath = '// * [@ id = "detailAttributFiche"] / div / p')%>% html_text ()%>% as.character ()

character (0)
```

As you can see, I always have a "character (0)" that appears, as if it couldn't read the whole page. I suspect some JavaScript part is not linking properly ...

How can I do ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The data is from this link (the `etatActiviteInst` parameter): https://www.georisques.gouv.fr/webappReport/ws/installations/etablissement/0030-12015

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me how you found this link ?

Comment: @Préliator Look at the Network tab in the Dev tool while loading the page.